# How to write a single fire and forget $inc query for MongoDB time series data in a complicated data structure

Tags: mongodb

Thank you in advance for assisting me with this MongoDB time-series data problem.

**Scenario**

I am writing an analytics feature for a chat application similar to Slack/ Discord. There are many "chat servers" which have many channels, which many users can type in.

For each chat server, I would like to increment a count of messages per user, per channel, per hour, per month every time a message is typed into a channel

I was thinking of having a document per month for each chat server so that I could automatically expire/ delete the document after one year in order to attempt to limit the size of each document (by not having every month in it), and the collection overall. But interested to hear thoughts on that.

**Goals**

I would like to display this data in graph form on a website with each month being the x axis datapoint where applicable. 
The kinds of queries I need are:

- A sum of all messages for all chat servers per month over the past 12 months.
- A sum of all messages in an individual chat server per month over the past 12 months.
- Most active chat servers per month over the last 6 months
- Most active channels in an individual chat server for the current month.
- Most active users in an individual chat server for the current month.
- The query to increment these counts must be a single fire and forget 
  query that will set/ create data where it does not already exist.

**Proposed Data Structure**

Through reading around I have come up with the following data structure that allows me to index by server_id and month:

```
{
    server_id: "1234567890",
    month: ISODate("2019-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    days: [{
        day: ISODate("2019-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        hours: [{
            hour: ISODate("2019-09-01T00:01:00.000Z"),
            channels: [{
                channel_id: "405983",
                users: [{
                    user_id: "111111",
                    messages: 44
                }, {
                    user_id: "333333",
                    messages: 87
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            hour: ISODate("2019-09-01T00:02:00.000Z"),
            channels: [{
                channel_id: "405983",
                users: [{
                    user_id: "111111",
                    messages: 33
                }, {
                    user_id: "333333",
                    messages: 22
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

The attempted query:

```
db.analytics.update({
    guild_id: "619633147906097194",
    "days.hours.channels.channel_id": "903488"
}, {
    $inc: {
        "days.11.hours.16.channels.$[].messages": 1
    }
}, {
    upsert: true
})
```

However, I can't get this to work. Error:
*The path 'days.11.hours.16.channels' must exist in the document in order to apply array updates.*

**Questions**

1. Is there a better data structure for the performance of the queries
   I'd like to write?
2. Is it a good idea to have a new document per month for each chat server 
   or is there a better way?
3. What would the single fire and forget query look like that will
   increment the message count (any help writing this would be
   appreciated, it's a bit beyond my current knowledge.
4. Are the aggregation queries that I need to write to display the data 
   meaningfully in graph form possible with this data structure in a
   single query per graph?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use mongo to do this, but consider the fact that you're trying to see this data over time, so you're going to have to solve the same issues that they've already solved in time series database.

Consider the fact that you will constantly be making writes and locking that table, so the main traffic in your mongo cluster will just be that table replicating to slaves. Then, anytime your users want to look at this data, you'll need to run a query against your application database - and if the application DB is in heavy use at the time from the write heavy load, your read time could potentially take a while.

When you want to graph time series data, you might want to use a time series database for your metrics. It makes it lighter to access/aggregate the information later, you can have much more detailed graphs that you can aggregate based on time, and there's already existing tools that make it easy to visualize the data on dashboards professionally.

The advantage of having separate metric and application DBs is that your reporting can be intensive as you want and your end users will never be impacted.

You would send in records for each chat event that have a timestamp and your data labels, keeping heavier elements (e.g. the text of the chat) in your application DB. You can add as many fields as you want and all of them would be graphable.

You might consider [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/) or the [AWS managed solution](https://aws.amazon.com/timestream/). Both of these can be pretty easily graphed using [Grafana](https://grafana.com/). It would be tricky to use Grafana directly on mongo.

If you care about performance overhead from a second DB write, you can create a sidecar process/thread that connects to your metrics DB. Communicate with the thread asynchronously using channels/queues (RabbitMQ,Celery,SQS)/whatever and it would be responsible for completing the write to the metrics server.

If you don't care all that much about precision, you can use prometheus/statsd, which are good at aggregating data and showing patterns. These tools are high performance but are meant for monitoring data (which depreciates in value over time) as opposed to business data (where data accuracy comparisons for year over year might be valuable.